# Configure an Asicminer Blade

Tags: asic

Just got my asicminer Blade yesterday and it is mining fine in slush pool via stratum proxy.
Now i want to switch the mining pool to another one. But how can i configure my mining_proxy exe?

Comment: I was just wondering ..did the BTCGuild one worked? what is the exact bat code to use with Workerusername (btc) and password(123) for BTCguild worker.Or you do not need them at all? Only this will suffice?
mining_proxy.exe -o eu-stratum.btcguild.com -p 3333

Answer (score 0):

Power on
Ethernet cable direct to router
Make sure your router's subnet is 1, ie 192.168.1.x
Using a browser navigate to 192.168.1.254:8000 - this goes to the blade's configuration page.
Change the ip to something useful like .200, and if you have multiple connect them one by one and change to .200, .201 etc. If you don't you'll have conflicting IPs and they'll conflict
We need to use a stratum proxy as these blades were designed for the extinct getwork protocol. Download the stratum proxy and open the file.
On the blade config page, enter the IP of the computer with the stratum proxy on as the server address. Enter it twice as the blade needs two pools to start mining, ie "192.168.1.102,192.168.1.102"
Username and password is for Slush's pool, stick with that for now
Click update, then go back to the config IP you set
Set clock to high by hitting change clocks

If you want to change pool, create a .bat file in notepad. Just save it as .bat in the file name. Move the stratum proxy to the location provided and put the following text inside for eu btcguild. Change pool port and address as required.

Quote
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxy
mining_proxy.exe -o eu-stratum.btcguild.com -p 3333

go to https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=205369.0

for full article